# Operation not permitted

Tags: sudo, chgrp

I have a server on Amazon ec2,
When I try to change group file (chgrp danny /tmp/bla) I get "Operation not permitted".
(I don't want to use "sudo")
Anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think what Mike Scott is trying to explain is that only root, or someone elevated with sudo, can use the chgrp command.

Comment: In another machine it works, see :      [06:57:01][ *danny* @ w1:~]$ whoami
danny
[07:26:54][ *danny* @ w1:~]$ touch /tmp/bla
[07:27:48][ *danny* @ w1:~]$ chgrp apache /tmp/bla
[07:27:55][ *danny* @ w1:~]$ ls -l /tmp/bla
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny apache 0 Apr 17 07:27 /tmp/bla

Comment: Check that the file A) doesn't exist before you test and B) isn't group-apache before the chgrp command.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` to allow a certain user to use only certain commands. For more information, please refer to `man sudoers`.

Comment: It should work without touching this file,
I do not want to give this user permissions
The file's owner user can confirm the file's group have
Another machine that worked for some, there is no reason it will not work

Comment: Maybe you have another idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a sticky bit issue. You can only change the group of a file if you have the right permissions and `/tmp` is a special directory where the permissions of files are set to be the creator of the file (the '[sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)' is set on /tmp).

So your example of going onto another machine and doing

```
$ touch /tmp/bla
$ chgrp newgroup /tmp/bla
```

would work fine as when you created the file with `touch` it was created with your user/group. So you are allowed to alter the group. However, if another user created a file in `/tmp` it would belong to them and your normal user `danny` couldn't do anything to it. This is what I think your issue is.

Here's the requisite section from the wiki page:

> When the sticky bit is set, only the item's owner, the directory's owner, or the superuser can rename or delete files. Without the sticky bit set, any user with write and execute permissions for the directory can rename or delete contained files, regardless of owner. Typically this is set on the /tmp directory to prevent ordinary users from deleting or moving other users' files.

Comment: But i create new file with "danny" user in /tmp or /test and I try change the group with danny to apache and I get the error... and if I try same on anther machine it's work... the machine is new and clean.. i can't see problem on machine.. and the operating system same on machins and the drives.. I do not understand it....

Comment: Sorry, you also can also only change the group to a group that you are part of. Add yourself to the apache group with `usermod -a -G apache username` (this will need to be done as root) and logout (you may need to reboot). You then should be able to change the group of that file.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you don't want to use sudo. Change that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Right answer, wrong way to present it.

Comment: This user is limited and I do not want to give him permission

Comment: You can give the user permission to run only the chgrp command with sudo and no other commands -- check the syntax for the sudoers file.